# Oracle: CaseState with ISNULL condition

Tags: oracle, case

I have the below case statement that is not capturing is null values. How can I add another criteria to capture when REGION_NAME is null

```
CASE WHEN M.OPER_STATE = 'AK' AND REGION_NAME IN ('NA','N/A','')
  THEN 'Pacific'
  ELSE T.REGION
END REGION
```

The folling row returns blank for region and should return Pacific.

```
Region    Id    REGION_NAME
          1      (THIS VALUE IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not check a value against `null` by checking if it's "equal" to `null` or to `''`; you need to use `IS [NOT] NULL`:

```
... (REGION_NAME IN ('NA','N/A') OR REGION_NAME IS NULL) ...
```

You could even use `NVL`, but I would prefer the boolean way for clarity:

```
... (nvl(REGION_NAME, 'NA') IN ('NA','N/A') ...
```